# Text goes off when i change the orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

i am working on an android application in which i have a slideshow of ten images at most and every image has associated text with it which is displayed. when i click/tap on some image the images is enlarged and text does not appear until i tap the screen again, that fine up till now. But when i change the orientation of the device or emulator then images is displayed but text portion displays null. which is definitely not required. the same text should be displayed as was before orientation change.

One more thing to make it clearer is that when null displays, and i change the slideshow image then text appears fine , but again when change orientation same thing repeats.

Help me avoiding this null. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When the orientation of the device changes the current page will be rebuilt. i think you don't download/parse/whatever the text again when it is rebuilt. you should check for that or provide code so we can look for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is happen because when you change orientation the current activity is destroy and start again and there you may not assign the value of textview.If possible provide some code so that we can find out what is going to be wrong.